# Why netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align allocates different size of sk_buffers?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

The next issue is regarding linux kernel buffers for managing network packets, as known as **sk_buff**.

- I'm running a code that every time that some event occurs it calls `netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align` to allocate a new skb with length of 1536 bytes.
- However, sometimes I see the allocated skb is with `skb->len=1536` (`skb->truesize=1984`), and sometimes with `skb->len=1792` (`skb->truesize=2240`).

**Question:** I guess it's not a bug... But does anyone can tell for sure if this is the correct behavior of the memory allocation mechanism of sk-buffers ? (an explanation or some reference to an explanation would also be nice).

Thanks

Comment: As for reference - you can always refer to `netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align` [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/skbuff.c#L425). You can see the exact changes to the length of the skb (due to alignments and padding). Regarding to your question - can you tell in which cases the length changes? Do you call the function in the same way? In what context you are?

Comment: @SpiderPig1297, I dig a bit into the code, and I think the allocator using some "best fit strategy allocation" (which is the best fit deals with allocating the smallest free partition which meets the requirement of the requesting process).  Thanks for your help!